# Open a file whose name changes every day

Tags: vba

I am creating a macro that needs to open a file whose name changes everyday. (ex: `abc_20190920`; next day: `abc_20190921`). How can I code the macro to find the file automatically?

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _ "Z:\Risk Management\KPMG reports\Macro\SFTP\Alternative_Investments_FCP_(RAIF)_4C_Report_20190827.xlsx"
```

Comment: To provide assistance, we need to see your code.  Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Z:\Risk Management\KPMG reports\Macro\SFTP\Alternative_Investments_FCP_(RAIF)_4C_Report_20190827.xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your filename is a string that contains a date.  Since the date needs to be dynamic, split your string into 3 pieces and concatenate them together.  The second piece is today's date formatted as needed:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Z:\Risk Management\KPMG reports\Macro\SFTP\Alternative_Investments_FCP_(RAIF)_4C_Report_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Present a user form with a list of the files and let the user pick the desired one to operate on. That way you can be assured of getting the right file. Otherwise you will need to generate the right filename from other available information to use in opening the file.